# Obtengo el error mientras ejecute la url "http://localhost:8000/crear-articulo"

Tags: django

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/crear-articulo

Using the URLconf defined in AprendiendoDjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    [name='index']
    inicio/ [name='inicio']
    hola-mundo-django/ [name='hola_mundo']
    pagina-pruebas/ [name='pagina']
    pagina-pruebas/<int:redirigir> [name='pagina']
    contacto-dos/ [name='contacto']
    contacto-dos/<str:nombre>/ [name='contacto']
    contacto-dos/<str:nombre>/<str:apellidos> [name='contacto']
    crar-articulo/ [name='crear_articulo']

The current path, crear-articulo, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: Hola. Las preguntas van en español, pues estás en SOes. Por favor, edítala y tradúcela

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el nombre del path en urls.py:

```
crar-articulo/ [name='crear_articulo']
```

Dice crar-articulo y debe decir crear-articulo

Comment: Eso mismo vi, buen ojo!!!

Comment: Hola juan  y jaime gracias por sus ayudas   y comentario ya encontre el error. muchisisimas gracias chicos por la buena onda simpre.